# QSqlDatabase and QSqlQuery in a Class (header)

Tags: mysql, database, qt, class

I want to create a class in my QT projecto, to handle the SQL Connection and all the necessary query's and sql transactions.

I've found that to not have this error "QSqlQuery::exec : Database not open" I had to only initialize the QSqlQuery AFTER the QSqlDatabase has been initialized and opened.

The problem is that I don't know how to do that...

There is my code :

```
private:
   QSqlDatabase MyDBConnection;

   // Efectua a ligação à DB
  bool MySqlCon()
  {
      MyDBConnection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
      if (!MyDBConnection.isValid())
          qDebug() << "ERRO DRIVER MYSQL";

      MyDBConnection.setHostName("localhost");
      MyDBConnection.setUserName("username");
      MyDBConnection.setPassword("password");

      if (MyDBConnection.open())
      {
          MySqlQuery = QSqlQuery(MyDBConnection);
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
          qDebug() << MyDBConnection.lastError();
          qDebug() << "Não Ligado Com Sucesso";
          return false;
      }
   }

public:
    QSqlQuery MySqlQuery;

    // Lê valores na DB
    void DBReader(QString Query)
    {
        if(MySqlCon())
            MySqlQuery.exec(Query);
        else
            qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Luis Da Costa

Comment: Please do not edit question titles to indicate [solved]. You can accept a provided answer or add your own answer explaining the solution and accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it you. 
From QT Doc :

> Warning: You must load the SQL driver
>   and open the connection before a
>   QSqlQuery is created. Also, the
>   connection must remain open while the
>   query exists; otherwise, the behavior
>   of QSqlQuery is undefined.

So create the Query object after you have opened the database (i.e declare it in method)

Comment: Sorry It was my fault XD.. my Query was wrong :S... If only I can use exceptions in Qt like in C# or Java... that will help me a lot !... Thanks ^^